# Error when deploying django app to heroku

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I am trying to push my app to heroku, but I am getting the following error:

```
Counting objects: 1907, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1894/1894), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1907/1907), 9.86 MiB | 2.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 1907 (delta 160), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/8790c95df255b386056ea169648fd4a33d1cb3fba81f73b536f26374f6af107145f64a5980db7a52177f63bb4152
7f360ebd2e3bef7b8917bda7b51cf284cfdb/bin/steps/python: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

remote: ) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mywebsite.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mywebsite.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mywebsite.git'
```

Any ideas? I have the Procfile, requirements.txt, and runtime.txt files

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.6.5
```

requirements.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.5
django-bootstrap4==0.0.7
django-ckeditor==5.6.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-js-asset==1.1.0
django-suit-redactor==0.0.4
django-summernote==0.8.11.4
gunicorn==19.9.0
Pillow==5.4.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
pytz==2018.9
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the runtime.txt to 3.6.7 instead of 3.6.5

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution, Heroku likes UTF-8 but not UTF-8-BOM.

Windows likes to use UTF-8-BOM, even if you select UTF-8, unless you specify without BOM it might assume with BOM.

Try and save your .txt file encoded specifically in UTF-8 without BOM.